# Move data to new table AND add new data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to achieve the following with one SQL query (for MySQL):

I want to move a row from one table to another table and meanwhile change two of its values.

Can I achieve this in **one query**?
The PHP code I have now:

```
$value1a = "Old value for this column";
$value1b = "New value for this column";
$value2 = "value2";

$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (date, value1b, value2, value3, value4)
            SELECT (date, value1a, value2, value3, value4)
            FROM table1
            WHERE value1a=? AND value2=?
        DELETE FROM table1
            WHERE value1a=? AND value2=?";
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($value1a, $value2, $value1a, $value2));
```

value2, value3 and value4 stay the same. 'date' should change to the current date (I previously used SQL function 'NOW()' for that). 'value1b' is a completely new value, with a different column name but the same datatype.

**Could it be possible that this is the answer?**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (date, value1b, value2, value3)
            SELECT (value3, value4)
            FROM table1
            WHERE value1a=? AND value2=?
        VALUES (NOW(), ?, value2, value3, value4)
        DELETE FROM table1
            WHERE value1a=? AND value2=?";
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($value1a, $value2, $value1b, $value1a, $value2));
```

Comment: So to clarify, the destination table will use `value1b` as its column name, with the same value `'New value for this column'` for _all rows_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing an `INSERT INTO ...SELECT FROM` statement, you can use static values directly in the `SELECT` list, as well as function calls (like `NOW()`). You may then construct the `SELECT` statement to include all the ultimately needed values in one go:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (date, value1b, value2, value3, value4)
  SELECT
    /* call NOW() in SELECT */
    NOW(),
    /* Use a static string for the value1b column */
    /* (the alias 'AS value1b' isn't really needed) */
    'New value for this column' AS value1b,
    /* These don't change, and are the actual column values from table1 */
    value2,
    value3,
    value4
  FROM table1
  WHERE value1a = ? AND value2 = ?
```

When executing the statement now, you will have only 2 parameters. You could also use a parameter rather than the static string for `value1b`. You will definitely want to do this if this value is derived from user input.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (date, value1b, value2, value3, value4)
  SELECT
    /* call NOW() in SELECT */
    NOW(),
    /* parameter here instead of static string.... */
    ?,
    value2,
    value3,
    value4
  FROM table1
  WHERE value1a = ? AND value2 = ?
```

...then call `execute()` with an array of 3 parameters.

```
$stmt->execute(array($value1b, $value1a, $value2));
```

The deletion statement must be executed as a separate statement, after successful execution of the `INSERT`. Assuming you want to maintain atomicity between these (your reason for wanting them as one query), wrap them in a transaction:

```
$DB->beginTransaction();
// Perform the INSERT
// On success, perform the DELETE
// And finally commit the transaction.
$DB->commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt is very close, but you just want to change the SELECT part slightly. You can select functions of values rather than just raw values, so your SELECT part can look like

```
SELECT (NOW(), value1a, value2, value3, value4) FROM table1 ...
```

This still isn't quite a single SQL statement, though, in that the DELETE line is a separate statement. You can't do the INSERT and the DELETE all in one go.

Why do you want to do it in a single statement, though? Is it because you want the two things to happen simultaneously? If so, you should look into transactions: that's what they're for. Start a transaction; do your INSERT; do your DELETE; then commit the transaction. Anything else that's looking at the database will see the whole thing done atomically (in other words, nothing will ever see the database with the row inserted but the other row not deleted).